# ArcTo() not drawing arc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Canvas Hello World</title>
    <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ArcTo</h1>
    <h2>Two arcs</h2>
    <canvas id="arcToNormalCanvas" width="500" height="500">HTML5 not supported
    </canvas>
    <hr />

    <h1>Simple drawing:</h1>
    <canvas id="rectangleCanvas" width="500" height="500">HTML5 not supported
    </canvas>
    <hr />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            doRectangleCanvas();
            drawTwoArcs();
        });

        function doRectangleCanvas() {
            var canvas = $('#rectangleCanvas')[0],
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.fillRect(50, 100, 150, 200);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function drawTwoArcs() {
            var canvas = $('#arcToNormalCanvas')[0],
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
            ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
            ctx.moveTo(300, 200);
            ctx.lineTo(400, 100);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
            ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
            ctx.arcTo(200, 200, 300, 200, 100);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the output is only the lines, with no arc!

[image: Canvas of html file above]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try just drawing the arc itself: `ctx.arc(250,200,50,Math.PI,Math.PI*2,true);`

Comment: I need to know this method, in particular.

Comment: After some research, I found that `arcTo` is only implemented in Firefox and Safari. You should see an error in your browser's console.

Comment: I am using Firefox, although the example I'm looking at is actually in a Microsoft Press book.

Answer (score 2):

`arcTo` is only supported by Firefox and Safari. For full browser support, you should use `arc`:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250,200,50,Math.PI,Math.PI*2,true);
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke();
```

Also, I have to ask, why on earth are you using `$('#rectangleCanvas')[0]` when you should be using `document.getElementById('rectangleCanvas')`?

Comment: I was in a jQuery mindset, although what is the problem with `$('#rectangleCanvas')[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect the two lines, which is what I think you want, I have to change this lines...

```
//...
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.arcTo(250, 250, 300, 200, 50);
// A radius of 100 is not what you want I believe.
// I used 50 for this example.
// You might want Math.cos(Math.Pi / 4) * 100, which is around 70.7

// You might also want to add here a line to actually connect with (300, 200). As if you use a too short or too long radius your arc will not be connected.
ctx.lineTo(300, 200);
ctx.stroke();
```

... As this function will define an arc between the two tangents not from point to point.

BTW, arcTo function is well supported in all major browsers that support the canvas element.